# What is the choice the Oracle couldn't see beyond?

Tags: the-matrix

When Neo meets the Oracle for the last time the following conversation takes place:

> **Oracle**: I hope I helped.
>
> **Neo**: You helped me to get here, but my question is why? Where does this go? Where does it end?
>
> **Oracle**: I don't know.
>
> **Neo**: You don't know or you won't tell me?
>
> **Oracle**: I told you before. No one can see beyond a choice they don't understand, and I mean no one.
>
> **Neo**: What choice?
>
> **Oracle**: It doesn't matter. It's my choice.

**What choice is she talking about?**

Comment: I couldn't find a nice youtube video showing the scene. If anyone can find one, please add it to the question.

Comment: The easy answer is Smith, but I think she understands that annoyance well enough.  So something further into the endgame.

Comment: The choice to go off - plan and help neo to break The Matrix.

Comment: I think it was the choice of letting Smith take control of her.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is outlined in Trinity and Morpheus' [earlier conversation](http://thematrixtruth.remoteviewinglight.com/html/revolutions-transcript-2.html) with The Oracle. Her "choice" is to have faith in Neo, to lead him into a sexual relationship with Trinity (creating the profound attachment that leads him into making the decision to take the left door) and into an open conflict with Smith rather than simply fulfilling her *normal* role of guiding him back to the Source to reboot the Matrix.

This is an **astoundingly risky** move on her part (one that could very easily lead to the death of the human race and the destruction of The Matrix) but she seems quite sanguine about her decision by this stage:

> **Trinity:** *What happened?*
>
> **Oracle:** *I made a choice and that choice cost me more than I wanted it to.*
>
> **Morpheus:** ***What choice?***
>
> **Oracle:** ***To help you, to guide Neo.***  Now, since the real test for any choice is how we make the same choice again, knowing full well what it might cost, I guess I feel pretty good about that choice, `cause here I am, at it again.

Answer (score -3):

I believe her choice was to tell Neo he wasn’t the one. It’s after that she tells him he will have to make a choice between himself and Morpheus. All of it leading to Neo awakening as the one and smith becoming a virus. But none of it would have happened had she told him that he was the one from the start.

> Oracle: Ohhh, what's really going to bake your noodle later on is, would you still have broken it if I hadn't said anything?

Answer (score -3):

When you make choices in life, usually you could see what rewards they will bring in the future. Before you a make choice to invest in Google, you would have made time to try to understand their business and then you make the choice to invest. You would not invest in me and my business if you don't understand me and my business because *"No one can see beyond a choice they don't understand."*

The Oracle chose to help Neo because what was happening had happened before like the Architect says *"She, undoubtable, would be its mother"* and *"This would be the 6th time we had destroyed it"*. She made that choice because she's been there before. Neo doesn't know this but the Oracle is giving him a clue like *"hey, I have been here before and so I know what is likely to happen if I help you"*.